# Grammar check module or extension in CME

Tags: cme, gui-extensions

Is there any Grammar-check module or Gui-Extension available? CME has only spell check option. One of our client asked for it. Has anybody integrated some third-party grammar check module?

Answer (score 5):

Good question. It's great to see clients trying to improve their content & editorial processes.

**Acrolinx** (http://www.acrolinx.com/) is 'content optimisation software' that provides the following four features:

1. Spell checking (incl. custom / domain specific dictionaries)
2. **Grammar checking**
3. Phrase / terminology checking
4. Checking against custom (content) style guides

I've never used it (I did chat to one of their sales team at SDL Innovate for quite a while), but they are an SDL technology partner, so **there should be a direct/easy integration with the Content Management Explorer (CME) available**.

They are also technology partners with other big CMS & Document Management Systems (incl. Sharepoint), so your client may be able to use Acrolinx across more than just their Tridion content.

I think that they also do a SAAS version, but there may be some limitations (as well as benefits) to this.

Answer (score 5):

SDL SafeGuard is a tool for quality control - http://www.sdl.com/products/safeguard/

I am not 100% sure if it does grammar, but I know it does spelling.

You can also setup custom compliance rules, for example `coke`, `coca cola`, `coca a cola` must fail the compliance test as it should always appear `Coca-Cola`.